# Flutter:How to get a value from flutter/provider change notifier

Tags: flutter

I have program where I need to add a count next to a bottom navigation icon. So, I am trying to use the ChangeNotifierProvider and wrap it around my root widget. How do I get the count from the IterableModel to my widget?

MAIN.APP

ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => IterableModel()),

HOME.DART

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
 icon: Container(
   margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
   child: ImageWithBadge(
      text: 'notification',
      iconData: Icons.mail,
      notificationCount: "NEED MESSAGE COUNT,
   ),
 ),      
),
```

IterableModel.dart

```
class IterableModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<InAppMessages> inAppMessages;
  int cnt;
  IterableModel({this.inAppMessages});

  void messageCnt(List inAppMessages) {
    cnt = inAppMessages.length;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  IterableModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['inAppMessages'] != null) {
      inAppMessages = [];
      json['inAppMessages'].forEach((v) {
        inAppMessages.add(new InAppMessages.fromJson(v));
      });
      messageCnt(inAppMessages);
    }
  }
}
```

I think i need a consumer and builder but I don't now where to place it

Answer (score 1):

```
final count = Provider.of<IterableModel>(context).cnt;
```

Insert this line at the top of your build method than it would be accessible but also rebuild the entire widget one better aproach is to use Consumer

```
Consumer<IterableModel>(
  builder: (context,model,_) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
icon: Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
child: ImageWithBadge(
  text: 'notification',
  iconData: Icons.mail,
  notificationCount: model.cnt.toString(),
 ),
 ),      
 ),
)
```